# how to pass the database fetched values from controller to view page using ajax and json

Tags: json, ajax, codeigniter

**how to pass the database fetched values from controller to view page  using ajax and json.i have a controller and model code but i dont know how to pass values from controller to view page**

**Controller**

```
public function supplier_get_data(){


        $query = $this->Profile_model->supplier_communication();

        echo json_encode($query);

    }
```

**model**

```
 public function supplier_communication(){
        $sql = $this->db->get('communication');
        $sql = $sql->result_array();
        return $sql;
    }
```

**view page**

```
<div class="left">

                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-md-1">
                                                    <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/xxxx.jpg" class="img-circle" width="30px" height="30px"/>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-md-11">

                                                    <div class="left_msg_block">



                                                        <div class="left_messagetext"><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="time">here i want to display the database values</a></div>
                                                  </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
```

Comment: How did you want your view page result?

Comment: Is that the pattern you need
`<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="time">value1</a>
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="time">value2</a>`

Comment: @ubm yes same patten i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code may helps you
Controller function

```
public function supplier_get_data(){


    $query = $this->Profile_model->supplier_communication();

    echo json_encode($query);

}
```

Model function

```
public function supplier_communication(){
    $sql = $this->db->get('communication');
    $sql = $sql->result();
    return $sql;
}
```

Ajax function

```
 function loadData()
    {
    $.ajax({
    type:"post",
    url:"<?php echo site_url('controllername/supplier_get_data')?>",
    dataType:"json",
    success:function(data){
      for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
     alert(data[i].columnanme)
      $('<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="time">'+data[i].columnanme+'</a>').appendTo('.left_messagetext');
      }
    }

  });
 }
```

Comment: in view page i want to fetch the values in this line <div class="left_messagetext"><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="time">here i want to display the database values</a></div>